# validations using jquery in codeigniter using xajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate

The validation is mot working, please specify the answer.
there is no validations working, the form is submitting without validations,
I am using the xajax in codeigniter

this is my view or form

```
<form name="frmcontact" id="frmcontact" class="contact-form" action="">

      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">

      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">

      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">

      <textarea class="message1" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
      <span class="error"> </span> 

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

    </form>
```

and my javascript is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    ;(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frmcontact").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }).validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                     number:false                
                },
                 email: {
                    required: true,
                     email:true               
                },
                 mobile: {
                    required: true,
                     number:true,
                     minlength:10,
                     maxlength:10         
                },
                 message: {
                    required: true

                }

            },errorElement: "span",
            messages: {
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            submitHandler: function(){
                xajax_contactsubmit(xajax.getFormValues('frmcontact'));
            }

        }); 

     });
 })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#frmcontact").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                 number:false                
            },
             email: {
                required: true,
                 email:true               
            },
             mobile: {
                required: true,
                 number:true,
                 minlength:10,
                 maxlength:10         
            },
             message: {
                required: true

            }

        },errorElement: "span",
        messages: {
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
            xajax_contactsubmit(xajax.getFormValues('frmcontact'));
        }

    }); 

 });
```

no need to handle and stop submit, the validate plugin will manage it by it self

Comment: ok please remove these lines too `;(function($) { ` in the start and `(jQuery);` in the end

Comment: is there any configuration for javascript ?,  I have loaded the javascript library in autoload.php file.

Comment: no. they are builtin in your browser, you dont need to do any extra thing ,

Comment: at the console , I am getting these two errors ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 

}(jQuery));

jquery...date.js (line 1182)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$("#frmcontact").validate({